# jQuery UI: show div on top of Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I click on sortable div elements, I need to show a div on top the sortable. [In this jsdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/dzSRR/15/), when I click on the sortable the orange div is supposed to be displayed on top, but  instead is displayed below. What's wrong with this code?

The Javascript:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

$( ".ui-state-default" ).bind( "click", function(e) {
    var menu = $('<div id="menu" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:orange;position:absolute" />');
    $( this ).append(menu);
    menu.css('top', e.clientY+'px' );
    menu.css('left', e.clientX+'px' );
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cause Z-Index, set z-index:1000; or more.

Z-index property set the stack order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to use z-index. By default z-index wont be there.
value of the z-index can starts from 0.

I have updated your fiddle and also i added

```
$('#menu').remove();
```

to show only one orange div when you click multiple times.
Hope this will help you out.

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately HaSuKrOnOs answered first